# Voltage stabilizer input/output current

Tags: voltage, current

What is the relation between  the input and output current  of a generic efficient ( not just a zener diode) DC voltage stablizer ie:
If the input voltage  equals 15 V  the stabilized  voltage equals 12V  and the output current equals 2A whats the input current of the stabilizer? Does the input current decrease with input voltage ?

Comment: Have a look on this [question/answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linear regulators (such as 78xx, LM317) the input current is equal to the output current, plus a little bit to power the regulation circuit.

For a switch mode regulator, the power input is equal to the power output plus a little for regulator inefficiency.

Comment: Short and sweet; +1.